# Selenium::WebDriver Wait (Ruby, Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium, webdriver

I have a ruby script that opens a browser.  I have it set to open Firefox first and then Chrome if FF fails for some reason - like FF gets updated and Selenium hasn't caught up yet.

The wait function/definition works fine for FF but always breaks Chrome.  Here is the relevant code for the Chrome browser startup:

```
b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = $BROWSER_IMPLICIT_WAIT
```

I'm fairly new to Selenium still and I user the wait.until command after declaring something like:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => $BROWSER_EXPLICIT_WAIT)
```

The above lines of code work fine in Firefox.  However, I'd like to run my scripts with both FF and Chrome.  Is there a way to do this in Chrome and FF?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what errors do u see?

Comment: This is what the implicit_wait command results in:
undefined method `driver' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fb753d86c browser=:chrome> (NoMethodError)

Comment: The wait = ... $BROWSER_EXPLICIT_WAIT) line appears to work just fine on my current dev machine.  Which is odd because I remember it specifically not working on my original dev machine (which has recently suffered a hard drive issue).  Since I can't repeat it I guess I won't worry about it for now.

Comment: Any thoughts on why the implicit_wait still causes issues and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See now that you provide the error it gets easier to solve.

The reason is that - you have named the selenium driver instance as `b`

but defining the implicit time as

`b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = $BROWSER_IMPLICIT_WAIT`

ie with `b.DRIVER`, hence the error message - `undefined method 'driver' for`

change your command to

```
b.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = $BROWSER_IMPLICIT_WAIT
```

Comment: When I first read this I thought no way is this the answer. The exact line I have for Chrome works for FF. But I decided to test it anyways. Turns out I'd fixed the FF to remove the driver portion (btwn b. and .manage). So voila it works. Thanks